# Getting ReactJS/TypeScript to work with new clean MVC5 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, typescript, npm

I've already tried nearly all available tutorials to get a simple MVC5 project to run using TypeScript and ReactJS.

Note: I've created the projects from scratch using using Visual Studio 2015, .NET 4.6.1 and the ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework), Empty 4.6.1 Template.

Some of the tutorials I already tried so far can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190418214819/http://www.codesmirk.com/?p=52), [here](https://medium.com/@lucavgobbi/using-react-with-typescript-on-visual-studio-39cd0a77fdd2#.bmusbm8w0), [here](https://templecoding.com/blog/2015/12/11/using-react-typescript-webpack-and-visual-studio/), [here](https://blog.tomduncalf.com/posts/setting-up-typescript-and-react/) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112002240/http://www.samulihaverinen.com/web-development/dotnet/2016/01/04/getting-started-with-react-mvc6-typescript/)

When trying to use webpack I always get the following error:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

In between I have some messages from `npm` saying

> npm WARN engine ts-loader@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"} (current: {"node":"5.4.1","npm":"3.3.4"})

whilst my node-version is the newest available.

I can't find a tutorial which works nor do I see what is going wrong here.

Comment: What version of Webpack are you using? What does you Webpack configuration file look like?

Comment: @Frxstrem Hard to say. I tried the `webpack.config.js` as given in the tutorial, simply copy & pasting as well as playing around myself. No matter what I have changed, the error was the same. Latest test was with `"webpack": "2.2.1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [Webpack 2](https://webpack.js.org/), but the tutorials you're using are likely designed for Webpack 1. There was a breaking change in the structure of the configuration files in Webpack 2, which means that you'll need to modify the configuration files for them to work with Webpack 2.

A guide for migrating to Webpack 2 can be found [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/). In particular:

- `modules.loaders` should be `modules.rules` instead ([more](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules))
- `modules.preLoaders` can't be used anymore ([more](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-preloaders-and-module-postloaders-was-removed))
- You should remove the empty string `''` from `resolve.extensions` ([more](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#resolve-extensions))

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look and try it. Any idea about the `current:{"node":"5.4.1"}` message?

Comment: @KingKerosin The warning is saying that the module is not supported on the version of Node that you're using (I assume that's because there's a bug or something on Node versions between 5.0 and 5.10). It may or may not affect you, but it's not related to the Webpack issue.